# Environment variable passed to bash script is empty inside function

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I have bash script: myscript.sh. Here is the content:

```
#!/bin/bash

function my_func {
    echo "my_func start"
    echo $MY_VARIABLE  # THIS PRINTS NOTHING
    echo "my_func end"
}

function func2 {
}

echo "after my_func"
echo $MY_VARIABLE # this prints "YES"
```

I want to call only function my_func from command line with environment variable "MY_VARIABLE". I launch script with this command:

```
MY_VARIABLE=YES source myscript.sh; my_func
```

Here is the output:

```
after my_func
YES
my_func start

my_func end
```

Variable $MY_VARIABLE inside my_func() is empty. I want that variable $MY_VARIABLE in my_func() were equal to "YES".

Comment: What documentation leads you to the expectation that your original code would work as described?

Answer (score 3):

You are only setting `MY_VARIABLE` for the environment in which `source` runs. Once that complete, `my_func` runs in your original environment. If you want `my_func` to have access, use

```
export MY_VARIALBE=YES; source my script.sh; my_func
```

`bash` doesn't have closures; when you define `my_func`, the shell isn't using the current value of `MY_VARIABLE` in the definition. It just creates a function that, when called, looks in the calling scope for the value.